# Looking for a date or range of dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table in MySQL like this:

```
events      startdate   enddate
festival    2014-07-01  2014-08-14
camping     2014-08-01  2014-08-14
party       2014-09-01  0000-00-00
picnic      2014-09-05  0000-00-00
```

In some case, there's only one valid column.

So, if both columns are valid dates, I need a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE startdate <= '2014-08-05' AND enddate >= '2014-08-05'
```

If second column is zero, I need a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE startdate = '2014-08-05'
```

But, is it possible to select all active events on a picked date, with only one SQL statement?

Comment: What exactly is the reason to downvote this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a seperate OR condition that tests for 0000-00-00 dates for each date column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE 
    (startDate <= '2014-08-05' AND endDate >= '2014-08-05') OR 
    (startDate ='2014-08-05' AND endDate = '0000-00-00') OR
    (endDate = '2014-08-05' AND startDate = '0000-00-00')
```